Installing module is not fixing Error: Cannot find module 'qs'
I have this error 
, I ran  npm install qs  and it still didn't fix it. As well as deleted and reinstalled package.json dependencies. No luck with that either. The error started randomly when i imported aws-sdk libraries to import secrets in order to deploy my website. I'm really stuck and don't understand why this won't work.
